# CloseHandle():Return value check require

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, return-value

I am using `CloseHandle()` to close the handle to a thread.
This is done towards the end of the program and hence cleanup operation should be irrespective of the return value of the `CloseHandle`

pc-lint reports error that, ignoring return value of function.

Kindly let me know if there will be any issue if ignoring the return value.

Comment: well one can't really do anything useful with the return value of `CloseHandle` because even if the function failed - then what? however, in debug mode, I would still check the return value and assert. it can detect all sorts of double free and such.

Answer (score 5):

Easy Answer: I don't think I've ever seen any code anywhere that checks the return value of a CloseHandle, nor has a CloseHandle *not* working ever been the cause of any bug I've ever seen in 15+ years of programming on Windows (YMMV).

Real Answer: Of course you should check the error return (of all methods that could return failure, all the time), assuming your application has a consistent error handling framework already in place you would simply work with that.  Failing to consistently check return values and assuming success is a recipe for bigger, often harder to understand, failures later in the code.

That said: Would I worry about CloseHandle *failing* during the application shutdown? Probably not. But thats only my 2 cents.